# What is the gun used by the Predator?

Tags: predator, predator-series

in 1987 [Predator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predator_(film)) movie, what is the gun type used by the alien creature on his shoulder?

**Does it shoot bullets like a normal gun or is it a Plasma Gun?**

[image: shoulder weapon]

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a screenshot from the movie.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a [Plasma caster](https://aliens.wikia.com/wiki/Yautja_Weapons) which is fired from the shoulder of the Yautja and it fires a plasma pulse, not bullets.

[Plasma caster](https://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Plasmacaster)

> **The plasma caster is a shoulder-mounted energy weapon.** A triangular
>   laser rangefinder is used to assist aiming the shot. The laser sight
>   can be part of the Predator's helmet, although some casters have their
>   own laser sights without need of a helmet. In both set-ups the plasma
>   caster moves with the Predator's field of vision. **It fires a bright**
>   **blue or gold plasma pulse in a straight line.** The pulse can be
>   controlled to fire with more **powerful charges ranging from minor**
>   **stunning/wounding blasts or powerful enough to sunder the atmospheric**
>   **plating of interstellar aircraft.** The plasma caster and respective
>   tracking servos are some of the most vulnerable articles of equipment
>   carried by the Predator, being easily damaged. The plasma caster can
>   also be used as a hand held weapon.

[image: picture of the shoulder weapon]

Comment: You may also want to cut n paste in the bit about it also being called a "***Plasma Cannon,[2] Laser Cannon[3] or Shoulder Cannon,[4][5]***" along with the sources of that info

Comment: @Valorum, the only canon name was the Plasmacaster was it not?

Comment: It depends what you mean as canon. The term "*Plasmacaster*" comes from a [computer game](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Predator:_Concrete_Jungle_(video_game)) whereas "*Plasma cannon*" is what the cast/crew called it in the "**Making of Predator 2: Weapons of Choice**" special feature on the DVD, "*Laser Cannon*" is what they called it in [one of the authorised novels](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_vs_Predator:_The_Last_of_His_Clan)

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean now.

Comment: "*Shoulder Cannon*" comes from [one of the games](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_versus_Predator_2) and a "[making of](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Aliens_vs._Predator:_Requiem:_Inside_the_Monster_Shop)" featurette from AVP: Requiem.

Comment: I recommend the author to play AvP (the original Alien vs. Predator. FPS game). Plenty of using the shoulder cannon there while playing Predator.